# how to customized fbfrienpickerview controller and show in custom table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

i have got all friends in array

```
 FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {


        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ ", friend.name);
```

how to display in grouped table view in one section.

How to change (tick) friends selection to some custom button of fbfriendpicker view controller

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue. So i stored all the friends info into a Array (includes dictionaries) and add that data into a UItableView. So same way i think u can do it.

Comment: Create a NSDictionary and add user information, then add it to a NSMutableArray.Like that you can create a Array of fb friends. So user the UITableView to show that. For the ticker u can use a UIButton in your senario.

Comment: how to send request in multiple friends?